# Появляется ошибка System.FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, парсер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите разобраться с ошибкой, попытки `TryParse` не увенчались успехом(((

```
class Program
    {
        const string data_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var csv_str = client.GetAsync(data_url).Result;

            //foreach (var data_line in GetDataLines())
            //    Console.WriteLine(data_line);

            //var dates = GetDates();
            //Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", dates));

            var russia_data = GetData()
                        .First(v => v.Country.Equals("Russia", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", GetDates().Zip(russia_data.Counts, (date, count) => $"{date:dd:MM} - {count}")));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //
        private static async Task<Stream> GetDataStream()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(data_url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        }
        //
        private static IEnumerable<string> GetDataLines()
        {
            using var data_stream = GetDataStream().Result;
            using var data_reader = new StreamReader(data_stream);
            while (!data_reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = data_reader.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    continue;
                yield return line.Replace("Korea,", "Korea -"); // тут происходит замена
            }
        }
        //Метод который получает все даты
        private static DateTime[] GetDates() => GetDataLines()
            .First()
            .Split(',')
            .Skip(4)
            .Select(s => DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .ToArray();
        //
        private static IEnumerable<(string Country, string Province, int[] Counts)> GetData()
        {
            var lines = GetDataLines()
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(line => line.Split(','));
            foreach (var row in lines)
            {
                var province = row[0].Trim(); // Trim - обрезает всё лишнее в строке (пробелы, спецсимволы)
                var country_name = row[1].Trim(' ', '"');
                var counts = row.Skip(4).Select(int.Parse).ToArray(); // ошибка 
                yield return (country_name, province, counts);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: И как мы можем вам помочь?

Comment: что нужен сделать чтобы код работал? :) abracadabra

Comment: Передавать в `int.Parse` строку, которую можно преобразовать в число

Comment: он читает строку где только цифры, и не может в int её преобразовать

Comment: Вы хоть документацию метода `int.Parse` читали? Где результат метода `GetDataLines`? Не хватает данных.

Comment: он не может не преобразовывать строку где только цифры в int

Comment: Да и возвращать кортеж из 3-х элементов – не самая лучшая идея

Comment: `foreach (var row in lines)` :) **`row`** в **`lines`**. Может `lines` -> `rows` или `row` -> `line` :)

Comment: вставил полный код и материал с которым работаю

Comment: Может вместо `.Select(line => line.Split(','));` надо `.Select(line => line.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));`?

Comment: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте просто отладить ваш код. Это может любой нормальный редактор (если брать Microsoft'овские, то это Visual Studio и VS Code). Посмотрите значения переменных в процессе выполнения метода.

Comment: щас дополню фото

Comment: вот вы скрыли самое интересное: св-во `Current`, ведь там и есть данные о строках

Comment: Попробуйте сами посмотреть и отладить ваш код. Пораскиньте мозгами – для меня это самая интересная часть.

Comment: line получил значения полностью, row получил значение полностью, код вроде бы выполняется вполне адекватно но на моменте var counts происходит counts = null и все, ему нечего парсить

Comment: Кстати, если вы хотите написать кросс-платформеное приложение, то никогда не используйте `"\r\n"` – используйте `Environment.NewLine` – получше будет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112051/discussion-between-edward-and-return).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip(4) => Skip(5)

```
private static IEnumerable<(string Country, string Province, int[] Counts)> GetData()
        {
            var lines = GetDataLines()
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(line => line.Split(','));
            foreach (var row in lines)
            {
                var province = row[0].Trim(); // Trim - обрезает всё лишнее в строке (пробелы, спецсимволы)
                var country_name = row[1].Trim(' ', '"');
                var counts = row.Skip(5).Select(int.Parse).ToArray(); // Верно!
                yield return (country_name, province, counts);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Этот ответ? Тогда уберите из кода комментарий `// ошибка`.

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил